# I want to insert a file into my SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server-2012

My `FileContent` table has 4 columns:

```
ID, FileName, FileType, [Content]
```

1. I want to put a unique constraint on the `FileName` column.
2. What should be the insert query if I want to insert a file from a specified location into the SQL Server database table?

Comment: Often, you are better off storing the file path in the database, rather than the actual file (which should be stored elsewhere). Have a read of this question to be sure you should put the file into the database ... http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/150669/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-store-large-files-10-mb-in-a-database

Comment: Did you Google SQL file upload?  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/225446/Uploading-and-downloading-files-to-from-a-SQL-Serv